# Win8: Wireless network connection drops intermittently

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 3520 64-bit running Win8, and the wireless connection drops once or twice a day for no apparent reason.  I have googled for solutions and have already unchecked the box "allow computer to turn off this device to save power" on my wireless adapter, but to no avail.  Additional info:

- Problem has occurred on 3 completely different wireless networks, so is unlikely to be an issue with the router.
- The other laptop in our house (Win7), as well as two iPads, work without any connection drops.
- Usually if I put the wireless adapter into "Airplane mode" -- which turns it off -- and then take it back out of airplane mode, the internet connection will return.

What can I do to fix this and get a reliable wireless connection?

Thanks!

Comment: try the latest drivers: ftp://ftp.dell.com/pages/Drivers/inspiron-15-3520-all.html#Network

Answer (score 0):

Try the [latest drivers](ftp://ftp.dell.com/pages/Drivers/inspiron-15-3520-all.html#Network) offered by your manufacturer.

If that doesn't help, then try a fresh OS/Windows install.

If those don't affect it, then based on all the other testing you did, it's probably a malfunctioning WiFi adapter in the Dell and it will need to go in for repair.